# Deviate reflection by percentage

Tags: c#, raytracing

I'm working on a raytracer with diffuse reflections (with say 64 or 128 samples per reflection).

For example, a material may be 75% reflective which means the reflected rays need to deviate from "perfect" reflection by 25%.

I've been trying to sort this out by calculating the reflected ray's right and up vectors and using percentages to multiply all three to combine into a deviated vector.

```
right = cross(intersectionNormal, ray)
up = cross(right, ray)
ray' = (ray * w) + (up * u) + (right * v)
```

I can't seem to get the math right. I've tried generating multipliers for each component based on spherical coordinates (random inclination at a random angle around the perfect reflection) but my math isn't working properly. The results never look like a semi-diffuse reflection. They look wrong. I'm using Random.NextDouble() to get random spherical coordinates within the material's reflectivity range.

Given a reflectivity between 1.0 (perfect) and 0.0 (diffuse), an intersection normal and a perfect reflection ray, how would I deviate this by the reflectivity percentage?

Answer (score 0):

From what you're trying to achieve it seems to me that "right" and "up" should not depend on the incoming ray's direction but just form an orthonormal basis with the normal. So you would choose `up = cross(right, intersectionNormal)`.

But instead of rolling you own, I'd suggest to just go with one of the standard reflection models like Blinn / Phong, where the exponent does pretty much what you want your reflectivity parameter to do.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have the right vector yet. I only have the incident vector and the normal. I have to generate the right vector from these. As for reflections, I'm already rendering the normal diffuse colour normally, but I want to enhance the reflection tracing method to use a diffuse scatter method (0.0 perfect reflection -> 1.0 fully diffuse) for diffuse reflections at a certain sample count per reflection (32-64 is a good number of samples).

Comment: You can choose the "right" vector whatever you like, it only has to be perpendicular to the normal. Your `cross(n, ray)` is generating bogus results for surfaces you view from straight above, but it's a starting point. But the third vector, `up` sould be perpendicular to `right` and `n`. Also, do you normalize these vectors before use?

Comment: I'm now using `norm([ Y, -X, 0 ])` to produce a perpendicular vector for `right` and doing `norm(ray x right)` to get the up vector (both arbitrary), but my math to combine those three into a final % deviated vector from `ray` is not working. I'm trying to use polar coordinates as one method.